# Is there a way to get a "zoom balloon" (like on the iphone) when sliding over a text input field?

Tags: keyboard, input-methods

Is there any way to show a zoom balloon (like on the iphone), whenever sliding over a text field to show us where the marker is, and allow us to move it correctly.

Comment: What phone and version of Android are you running?  Some alternative methods are available, but it's dependent on the hardware and software.

Answer (score 2):

My Motorola Defy has this capability.  My phone is running Android 2.1.  When you hold your finger over the text field, it will pop up a zoomed in window that allows you to move the cursor with your finger to edit text.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is a Motorola added feature?

Comment: I have pop-up zoom when selecting text, and nice cursor "handles" for both selecting text and moving the cursor when I type.  This is on my Samsung phone (using the stock Android keyboard).

Comment: @Matthew - what phone / ver?

Comment: @Sparx Vibrant / 2.2 (Bionix 1.3).  2.3 keyboard